# Issue when creating generic extension method

Tags: c#, generics

Right now I'm trying to create a generic method for including foreign keys in my repository.

What I currently got is this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    private static IQueryable<T> IncludeProperties<T>(this DbSet<T> set, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<T> queryable = set;
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            queryable = queryable.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        return queryable;
    }
}
```

However when compiling I get the error:

> The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter
>   'TEntity' in the generic type or method
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Append `where T : class` to the end of your method signature:

```
private static IQueryable<T> IncludeProperties<T>(
    this DbSet<T> set,
    params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
    where T : class // <== add this constraint.
{
    ...
}
```

`DbSet<TEntity>` has this constraint, so in order for your `T` type argument to be compatible with `TEntity`, it must have the same constraint.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, the generic argument to `DbSet` must be a reference type.  Your generic argument could be anything, including non-reference types.  You need to constraint it to just reference types.